# Docker: show running containers with links

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use `docker-compose` to create a few containers and create links between them. Assume I have a container called `a` running which has a link to `b` which is also running.

Can I easily inspect running containers to see which containers link to which?

I note that `docker ps` lists running containers along with some helpful info, like what ports are exposed. Likewise `docker-compose ps` provides the same kind of info. Neither appears to include an option to show links.

**Edit**

I try to `docker inspect` my running containers, per [Erazihel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4693496/erazihel)'s answer below, and it looks like I have no links.

```
$ docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.Links }}" docker_auth_1
[]
```

Perhaps docker-compose doesn't use links in the same way as it used to?

Assume I have a `docker-compose.yml` that looks something like:

```
services:
  auth:
    image: my-auth-image
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - integration
  db:
    image: my-db-image
    networks:
      - integration
networks:
  integration:
    external: true
```

Perhaps my use of "networks" affects how links are shown?

I am on macOS Sierra running Docker Version 17.06.0-ce-mac18 (18433).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command shows the containers in the ***integration*** network.

```
docker network inspect -f '{{json .Containers}}' integration | python -m json.tool
```

To get more specific:

```
docker network inspect -f '{{range .Containers}}{{println .Name .IPv4Address}}{{end}}' integration
```

Edit it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Communication across links documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links).

You can get the link of a `Docker container` using the `Docker inspect` command:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.Links }}" <name_of_your_container>
```

Let's take a container `web` for example:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.Links }}" web
```

It outputs something like:

> [/db:/web/db]

You can see that the `web` container is now linked to the `db` container `web/db`.

Here is more [documentation about `docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think there's a complication with my setup. I have edited my question with some more information.

Comment: You should use links in your docker-compose instead of networks

Comment: Links are deprecated.

Comment: @RicardoBranco, `docker run --link` is deprecated. Docker compose links not: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

Comment: It is "deprecated" (considered legacy, for now) in Docker Compose too, as it uses the underlying functionality of `--link` in the Docker Engine.  See:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links

"Starting with Version 2, links are a legacy option. We recommend using networks instead."

Comment: @RicardoBranco, you've pointed out about `external_links:` that does use the deprecated `--link`. However, `links:` has not the deprecation note, because it is not deprecated, only shares the same name. And it uses docker-networks behind. It is a bit confuse anyway.